# Неожидаемое поведение элементов при перетаскивании мышью

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, svg

При перетаскивании элементов с помощью мыши,  элементы перемещаются только вниз и вправо независимо от движения мыши.

Другие, [подобные вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010682/how-can-i-move-svg-element-by-mouse) похожи, но они не помогли решить проблему.

Можно ли смешивать `getBoundingClientRect` с манипулированием атрибутами `x` и `y` элемента?

Поскольку атрибуты могут содержать процентные значения, мы используем `getBoundingClientRect` в качестве основного значения для позиции элемента.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVKvgp

```html
var selectedElem = $("#imageBox1");
var isMoving = false;
var mouseLastX = null;
var mouseLastY = null;

$(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
   isMoving = true;
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(e) {
    isMoving = false;
    mouseLastX = null;
    mouseLastY = null;
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
     // Ignore if not moving
     if (!isMoving) {
        return;
     }

     // Exit if attempting to move, but no element is selected.
     if (!selectedElem) {
        console.log("Error moving element: no selected element.");
     }

     // If here, move selected element.
     // Get current mouse position.
     var mouseCurX = event.pageX;
     var mouseCurY = event.pageY;

     // Set last position? Must check null explicitly in case values are 0.
     if (mouseLastX == null || mouseLastY == null) {
        mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
        mouseLastY = mouseCurY;
     }

     // Get current values for selected element.
     var elemClientRect = selectedElem[0].getBoundingClientRect();
     var elemX = elemClientRect.x;
     var elemY = elemClientRect.y;

     // Set deltas.
     var deltaX = mouseCurX - mouseLastX;
     var deltaY = mouseCurY - mouseLastY;

     // Set new element position.
     var newX = elemX + deltaX;
     var newY = elemY + deltaY;

     // Store mouse position.
     mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
     mouseLastY = mouseCurY;

     // Update element.
     selectedElem.attr("x", newX);
     selectedElem.attr("y", newY);
});
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53908278/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Есть пара замечаний:

1. `getBoundingClientRect` даст вам `x` и `y` относительно страницы, однако атрибуты `x` и `y` вычисляются относительно родительского контейнера.
2. Начальные атрибуты `x` и `y` для `imageBox1` оба равны `25%`, поэтому вы не можете просто добавить к этому пиксели, вам нужно использовать формат `calc(25% + << delta >> px)`

Вот как заставить изображение двигаться так, как вы хотите:

```js
var selectedElem = $("#imageBox1");
var isMoving = false;
var mouseLastX = null;
var mouseLastY = null;

$(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
   isMoving = true;
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(e) {
    isMoving = false;
    mouseLastX = null;
    mouseLastY = null;
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
     // Ignore if not moving
     if (!isMoving) {
        return;
     }

     // Exit if attempting to move, but no element is selected.
     if (!selectedElem) {
        console.log("Error moving element: no selected element.");
     }

     // If here, move selected element.
     // Get current mouse position.
     var mouseCurX = event.pageX;
     var mouseCurY = event.pageY;
  
     // Set last position? Must check null explicitly in case values are 0.
     if (mouseLastX && mouseLastY) {

       // Get current values for selected element.
       var currX = selectedElem.attr("x");
       var currY = selectedElem.attr("y");
       var elemXpct = parseInt(currX.match(/\d+(?=%)/));
       var elemYpct = parseInt(currY.match(/\d+(?=%)/));
       var elemXpxls = parseInt(currX.match(/\d+(?=px)/) || 0) * (/-/.test(currX) ? -1 : 1);
       var elemYpxls = parseInt(currY.match(/\d+(?=px)/) || 0) * (/-/.test(currY) ? -1 : 1);

       // Set deltas.
       var deltaX = mouseCurX - mouseLastX;
       var deltaY = mouseCurY - mouseLastY;
       
       // Set new element position.
       var newX = elemXpxls + deltaX;
       var newY = elemYpxls + deltaY;
       
       var newXsign = newX < 0 ? '-' : '+';
       var newYsign = newY < 0 ? '-' : '+';
       
       // Update element.
       selectedElem.attr("x", `calc(${elemXpct}% ${newXsign} ${Math.abs(newX)}px)`);
       selectedElem.attr("y", `calc(${elemXpct}% ${newYsign} ${Math.abs(newY)}px)`);
     }
  
     // Store mouse position.
     mouseLastX = mouseCurX;
     mouseLastY = mouseCurY;

});
```

```css
.imageBox {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="rootBox" width="375" height="812" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  
    <rect x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="beige" />
  
    <svg id="imageBox1" class="imageBox" x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%">
       <image class="image" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzm1y7tjrhl872s/Screenshot.png?raw=1" />
       <image class="frame" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/6njspwfz2hgfd03/iPhone_X_Black.png?raw=1" />
    </svg>
    
</svg>
```

Примечание переводчика:

Связанная тема на RUso: [Drag & Drop всех элементов JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/901734/28748)

Comment: Оставлю это здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901856/265406 Может кто увидит и ему пригодится, а то, человек спросил и потерялся)

Comment: @UModeL ну, а мне придется отбиваться от любителей присваивать дубликаты. А то как же, ведь есть же слова - перетаскивание мышью :))))) Сейчас добавлю твой ответ сюда, как связанную тему

Comment: мой ответ только частично связан и не отвечает на вопрос. Просто, в ответе по ссылке, старался максимально лаконично реализовать именно DnD.

Comment: @UModeL новый вариант ответа, если  появится желание, напиши здесь. Тем более, как я обнаружил переводной вариант не работает в `FF`

Comment: _Желание есть, времени нет... Новый год..._ Вот такое хокку))